# How to write a test that expects an error to be issued in java

Tags: java, kotlin, testing

I am testing this feature:

```
fun findByUsername(username: String): Account {
        return accountRepo.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow {
            UsernameNotFoundException("Username was not found")
        }
    }
```

here is my test

```
@Test
    fun checkFindByUsername() {
        val userRegistrationForm = UserRegistrationForm("testUser3", "123", "eee", false)
        val user = accountService.createAccount(userRegistrationForm)

        assertEquals(accountRepo.findByUsername("").orElseThrow {
            UsernameNotFoundException("Username was not found")
        }, "Username was not found")
    }
```

what to do to make the test pass?
Do you need to use any specific assertion?
sorry, understand that stupid question

Comment: when i ise assertThrows, appearts error: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that you're using JUnit (5), you can use `Assertions.assertThrows`.

```
Assertions.assertThrows(UsernameNotFoundException.class, () -> 
    accountRepo.findByUsername("")
);
```

Comment: when i ise assertThrows, appearts error: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Comment: Then it seems like the Exception is no thrown...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `expected` parameter of the `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test(expected = UsernameNotFoundException.class)
```

Comment: I would recommend using `assertThrows` over this if JUnit 5 is available, because it specifies the exact point where the exception is expected and acceptable.